# how to save List-view position when back to previous Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, scrollview

I have a ListView with huge amount of data.But when i go to next page on ListView Item Click and come back to ListView. **I want the list to be scrolled to the same point that it was previously**.Can someone help to achieve this.

I tried this code.List to be scrolled to the same point but immediately come to the first position.

```
private void populateList() {
        descArray.clear();
        List<All_Post> allDesc = dbhelper.getAllDescriptions();
        for (All_Post all_Post : allDesc)
        {
            descArray.add(all_Post);
        }

        if (adapter == null)
        {
            adapter = new AllPostAdapter(this, R.layout.allpostlist, descArray);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else if (adapter != null) {


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter = new AllPostAdapter(this, R.layout.allpostlist, descArray);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            //int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            //listView.setSelection(firstPosition);

            int index = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
            int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - listView.getPaddingTop());
            listView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is default property of listview.

`if you move to next page on ListView Item Click and come back to ListView it will show same position`.

just keep one thing in mind that, ***you should not refresh your listview on backpressed() or when you are coming back to listview or any otherway you are using to moveback to listview*** .

Comment: it means does not call this method adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: yes, do not call that method. when you are moving back to listivew and it will retain same position. @p.ld

Comment: But this use only for backpressed() and what about other buttons like simple button like previous_button.

Comment: on previous_button you must be using backpressed(). so would just say do not refesh listview while getting back to listiview so your position will not change in listview. @p.ld

Comment: I have removed this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  and List is working fine , But when i take some button and go to   previous list at same position  on that click then how to work .But don't understand this on previous_button you must be using backpressed().

Comment: you can use backpressed() to move back but dont code to refresh listview inside that. its done. @p.ld

Comment: it means super.onBackPressed();  this method i have to use in button click method .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100006/discussion-between-p-ld-and-amit-vaghela).

Answer (score 2):

You can save the position of the list view item click in `OnItemClickListener` of your **listView**.
use that position when you comeback to **listView** and scroll to that position using

```
- listView.smoothScrollToPosition (position)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the position in saveInstanceState and then fetch the same position when you come back to the same activity(if you are destroying the activity) or
When you click the item, you can save the position and the use it(if you are not destoying the activity).

Then, once you have the position, you can use:

For direct scrolling, use :
getListView().setSelection(position);

For smooth scrolling, use :
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(position);

Answer (score 1):

try this: `public int pos_clicked = -1;
    on list view item click :
    pos_clicked = listView.getFirstVisiblePostion();`

**on come back:**`if(pos_clicked != -1)
        listView.setSelection(pos_clicked);`